# Unable to get Dialog/Splash Screen to appear

Tags: android, dialog, splash-screen

I am attempting to create a splash screen to show up while my app initializes, using the dialog method discussed here:

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

Yet, no matter what I do, the splash screen never appears, the screen just stays black until the main screen fully instantiates.. I call m.dismiss() at the end of the setup() method.

No errors are thrown, and the launch.XML is simply a linearlayout with a match_parent width and height and with a button taking up the enti view, but it never appears..

I assume it is either the context of "THIS" should be something else, or the width/height should be something other than match parent...  any ideas/help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    m = new Dialog(this,R.style.SplashScreen);
    m.setContentView(R.layout.launch);
    m.setCancelable(false);
    m.show();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post( new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                setup();
            }
    });
```

LAUNCH.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/button1"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your setup method is run on the UI thread. it prevents the spashscreen from being displayed. Try using an asynctask for the setup, and dismiss the splash in the onPostExecute()

Comment: No dice...  Code now looks like:

Comment: final class InitializeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  protected void onPreExecute(){
   m.dismiss();
  }
  
  protected void onPostExecute()
  {
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   setup();
   return null;
  }



 }

Comment: `code` 
         @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  m = new Dialog(this,R.style.SplashScreen); 
  m.setContentView(R.layout.launch);
  m.setCancelable(false);
  m.show();
  setContentView(R.layout.main);    
  new InitializeTask().execute();
    }

Comment: But still same behavior. The Dialog never appears.

Comment: "dismiss the splash in the onPostExecute()", not in the onPreExecute

Comment: DOH!  Put the dismiss in the PRE not the POST.. that seems to have done it.. now to figure out why setting up various things in a secondary thread has started other problems... thanks